# Appending rows to DF, following a strategy, if not already in DF twice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, append

QUESTION

What is the quickest/best (most pythonic) way of continuously (1000 times) add a set (e.g 35) of rows to a df (e.g. 40000 rows), if the criteria for each ID of that row is that the ID of that row is not already twice in that df, and the ID should follow from a certain strategy (e.g. the lowest possible number)?

CONTEXT

A compartment in a warehouse can hold a maximum of two different items. The location is given by a locationID (A115.14604A0) that I can split up in Tower (A), floor (11), aisle (5), column (146), shelf (04) and lastly, compartment (A0). I get only a line when an item exists. Example:

```
    Date        item ID             location_id     ean             quantity    volume  total v
0   2020-08-17  9200000074604211    A115.14604A0    7710958034710   1           820000  820000.0
1   2020-08-17  9200000122486821    A123.12702E1    2407047440917   2           450000  900000.0
```

So there is never a line when quantity is 0. Hence not all locations can be 'looped over' by the DF itself (although this is not a good solution anyway I think).

I need to 'fill' this df with new items, but I never have to add/change numbers in the original stock file, only append new rows. So items will always form a new row, but can have the same location ID with a maximum of two times. This format needs to stay the same.

STRATEGIES I HAVE THOUGHT OF:

1. Original plan
   Group by stock on unique Item_ID, create column (nr_unique)
   Join with an empty template of the DF, to get all the locations (if no match, nr_unique = 0)
   For loop over Tower (A), floor (11), aisle (5), column (146), shelf (04) and lastly, compartment, following a certain logic (for instance start with lowest tower).
   If quantity of a location is < 1, append a new line to the original stock file. Repeat this (1000 times) for each new set (35) of items.
2. NOT pythonic, bit smarter

For loop over Tower (A), floor (11), aisle (5), column (146), shelf (04) and lastly, compartment, following a certain logic (for instance start with lowest tower). If not in DF, create (concatenate) & append, if only once in DF, create (concatenate) & append, if twice or more in DF, continue in loop.

Repeat (1000 times) for each new set (35) of items.

3. Dumb vectorized method

Group by stock on unique Item_ID, create column (nr_unique)
Join with an empty template of the DF, to get all the locations (if no match, nr_unique = 0)
Get all rows where N <2
Select x rows based on strategy (for instance where aisle is lowest)
For my original DF, select those rows.
Add 1 to all those (or loop over them if you want everything to be fully filled to 2)

Repeat (1000 times) for every set (35) of items.

4. ????? there must be a smarter way to do this?

EVALUATION

I really lean towards 1 but everywhere I look people warn me for looping over dataframes. This needs to loop over all items every time. Hence it will be slow. What I am looking for is a way to add rows to my df in a pythonic matter.

Regards,
Charles

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a class that produced separate compartments, filling each one with items and volumes.